# Close Alert Window

Tags: java, switch-statement, window, alert, frame

I need help, while doing some practices using  BestBuy website , I face this issue I couldn’t figure it out how to handle that ( that drop down Box) to test some elements , When the website launch that dropdown Box open as on the picture please if any inputs to solve this thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07vcg.jpg)

Comment: So... are you using Selenium or what? Don't skimp on the important details -- people aren't going to want to help you if you start out with a guessing game.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry , I forget to add the details, yes Using Selenium with Java , Error"no such element: Unable to locate element. This is the code(
                                                                    static void setupClass()  {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/")                               driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"shop-todays-popular-picks-70321868\"]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();